# Crystal report - two fields from one dictionary

Tags: join, crystal-reports, multiple-columns

I want to show Matches played by two players

Table Payers is:

| PlayerID | Player_Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | John Creek |
| 2 | Alex New |
| 3 | Alvin Reed |

And matches table is:

| Player1ID | Player2ID | Result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 2-9 |
| 2 | 3 | 4-7 |
| 1 | 3 | 5-5 |

I want to show Full names in report

| Player 1 Name | Player 2 Name | Result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John Creek | Alex New | 2-9 |
| Alex New | Alvin Reed | 4-7 |
| John Creek | Alvin Reed | 5-5 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To complete this you will want the Players table to be added to the Selected Tables in Database Expert twice.  When you add a table more than once, it will prompt you to confirm this is what you want to do since the table has already been selected once.  After you confirm this, you should see the table listed twice, with the second listing appending an underscore and a number that indicates the number.

So you should now have a Players table and a Players_1 table.  (Players_1 is an alias, and can be renamed by right-clicking on the table name in the Data tab.)

Then on the Links tab of Database Expert you can join MATCHES.PLAYER1ID to PLAYERS.ID and then join MATCHES.PLAYER2ID to PLAYERS_1.ID.